# How I get common values from two query in a table and join it with another table in MySql?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables. One is **orders** and another is **users**. I want run two different query on **orders** table and want to get the common values and join it with **users** table.

```
    orders
    ======
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | id | user_id | receive_id | arrival_id | departure_id |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 1  |   1     |     1      |    null    |      5       |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 2  |   2     |     1      |      3     |      6       |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 3  |   3     |     1      |    null    |      7       |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 4  |   1     |     3      |      5     |    null      |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 5  |   3     |     3      |      6     |    null      |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 6  |   4     |     3      |      7     |    null      |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
    | 7  |   1     |     4      |      7     |      9       |
    +----+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

```
    users
    =====
    +----+---------+
    | id |   name  |
    +----+---------+
    | 1  |  Shaon  |
    +----+---------+
    | 2  |  Rabu   |
    +----+---------+
    | 3  |  Asha   | 
    +----+---------+
```

1st Query..

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders where receive_id = 1 and departure_id != 'null'
```

```
Its result will be..
1 2 3
```

2nd Query..

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders where receive_id = 3 and arrival_id != 'null'
```

```
Its result will be..
1 3 4
```

I want get common values form those queries

```
That is ..
1 3

When I Join it to users table then result will be
_id__name__arrival_id__departure_id
 1  Shaon    null           5
 3  Asha     null           7
But now I want to see..
_id__name__arrival_id__departure_id
 1  Shaon     5             5
 3  Asha      6             7
on arrival_id row the value from where 
receive_id = 3 there's arrival_id as distinct user_id

I think code will be like bellow. But It's not working.
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders where receive_id = 1 and departure_id != 'null'
COMMON
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders where receive_id = 3 and arrival_id != 'null'
JOIN users on (users.id = orders.user_id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get what you need by putting one query as a subquery for the other.
Something like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders
JOIN users on (users.id = orders.user_id)
where receive_id = 1 and departure_id != 'null'
and user_id in (SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders where receive_id = 3 and arrival_id != 'null')
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But you missed to Join with users table.

Comment: The following code returns the distinct column user_id.Beside these If I want to see all column then what I will do?

Comment: If you want to see all columns, you will have to `select *` instead of `select distinct user_id`. You should not use distinct user_id here in this case since the other column's values will be different for same user in different rows.

Comment: If you want to select all columns of a specific table, then you can use `select tablename.*`. Eg: `select orders.* from` or `select users.* from`

Comment: I want distinct value in terms of user_id but also want all column then what I will do?

Comment: Does one user have a distinct value or can have multiple values for other columns ? How are you expecting you output to be ?

Comment: There can be multiple values for other columns.  
id  name   departure_id  
1  Shaon         5  
3  Asha           5

Comment: Okie. But Shaon is having 2 rows. One with Departure Id 5 and another with 9. On what basis do you want to select the row ?

Comment: If you want any one of them, then you can keep `select distinct user_id, departure_id, id` in the select. It will give you the one that comes first. As in departure_id 5 and 9, 5 would come.

Comment: Thank @Venkata  for your reply I solved the problem as your reply.

Comment: I face another problem. For your better understanding I added some values on main questions. I want to see name, arrival_id, departure_id column. As following query it usually shown >> Shaon null 5 but want to see Shaon 5 5 here 5 from where receive_id = 3 as distinct user_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id from orders JOIN 
users on (users.id = orders.user_id) where receive_id = 3 and 
arrival_id != 'null' AND user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id from 
orders   where receive_id = 1 and departure_id != 'null');
```

You can use this query to fetch records

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
select orders.id, users.id from orders inner join users 
on orders.user_id = users.id
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.